# string not being recognised in C

Tags: c

here is my code where ever i use string it says unknown type name. i have tried to include  but still not working.I do not get it what is happening here. any help will be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
string  getname(string);
int getclass(int);
float calculation(int);
int main()
{
    string str2=getname();
    printf("name of student is %s \n",str2);
    int b=getclass(b);
    printf("class = %d \n",b);
//  float per=calculation(/*marks kithy ny??*/);
//  printf("percentage = %f \n",per);
    getch();
    return 0;

}
string getname(string str /* str likhdy nay ithy variable da nam sirf is nal coma nhi landay */)
{
    printf("enter the name of student \n");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    return str;
}
int getclass(int a)
{
    printf("enter the class \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
float calculation(int marks)
{
    printf("enter the marks \n");
    scanf("%d",&marks);
    int per=marks*100/550;
    return per;
}
```

Comment: There is no standard `string` class type in c, there are no classes in c.

Comment: This looks like CS50 thing. You should have used their "skeleton" file with all of the includes.

Comment: You are likely confusing c and c++. You may be reading tutorials or guides for c++ assuming it's c. They are different languages.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux what should i do than?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes ive been programing in c++ lately and new to c

Comment: Replace `string` with `char *`, there is no `string` type in C, only in with CS50. So if you use CS50, include the cs50 header file and be aware that `string` is actually `char *`; the CS50 `string` has nothing to do with the the c++ `string`, not even remotely. If you never heard of CS50 that's fine then do as recommended at the beginning of that comment.

Comment: I think the problem here is simply that C is not C++. The CS-50 trash wouldn't help, since that would just mean writing data into an uninitialized pointer. The correct approach is to learn how string handling works in C. Something best not learnt from CS-50 or other such questionable online tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

`string` is not a `C` type. Replace function parameter `string` with `char *`.

```
char* getname(char*);
```

Since arrays passed as pointers in `C` this will work. And use char arrays to store string values.

```
char str2[10];
getname(str2);
```

One last thing, do not use the `&` operator in scanf with arrays or pointers. Use:

```
scanf("%s", str);
```